# How to align a list in a div?

Tags: html, css

I need to make a vertical menu and the text is too far off, as you can see here. How can I align the list to make it fit inside the div?

```css
body{
   background-color: #018c24
}

li{
  list-style: none;

}

.contenedor{
  background-color: white;margin: auto;width: 70%;height: 800px;
  padding-top: 4px;border: 2px solid black;border-radius: 4px;
  padding-left: 4px;padding-bottom: 4px;padding-right: 4px;
}

.banner{
  background-image: url(http://www.librosweb.es/website/css/images/logo.gif);
  width: 99%;margin: auto;height: 15%;border-radius: 4px;
}

.about{
  display: table;margin: 0 auto;text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 10px;font-family:sans-serif;font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}

.about li{
  display:inline;margin: 3px;cursor: pointer;
}

.about li:hover{
  background: #f09d28;color: #000;
}

.about p{
    border-radius: 4px;display: none;background-color: #f15647
}

.nav {
  width: 20%;height: 81%;border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;float: lefT;
}

.nav ul{
  text-align: left;
}

.principal{
  width: 78%;height: 81%;border: 2px solid black;float:right;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
       <link href="C:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\main.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\prueba.js"></script>

       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>Título de esta página</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="contenedor">
          <div class="banner">
          </div>

          <ul class="about">

                <li>Quiénes somos  </li>
                <p class="caca">CACAasd</p>
                <li>Dónde estamos  </li>
                <p class="caca">CACAasd</p>
                <li>Contacto</li>
                <p>CACAasd</p>

          </ul>

          <div class="nav">
            <ul>
              <li>AAAAAAAAAAA</li>
              <li>BBBBBBBBBBB</li>
              <li>CCCCCCCCCCCCC</li>
              <li>DDDDDDDDDDD</li>
              <li>EEEEEEEEEEEE</li>
              <li>FFFFFFFFFF</li>
              <li>GGGGGGGGGGGG</li>
              <li>HHHHHHHHHHH</li>
              <li>IIIIIIIIIII</li>
              <li>JJJJJJJJJJJJ</li>
              <li>KKKKKKKKKKKKK</li>
              <li>LLLLLLLLLLLLLL</li>
              <li>MMMMMMMMMM</li>
              <li>NNNNNNNNNNNN</li>
              <li>ÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑ</li>
              <li>OOOOOOOOOOO</li>
              <li>PPPPPPPPPP</li>
              <li>QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ</li>
              <li>RRRRRRRRRRRRRR</li>
              <li>SSSSSSSSSS</li>
              <p>ACA</p>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="principal"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its easy when using [Chrome-](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), [Firefox-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) or [IE-](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx) dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your `ul` tag (by default) has padding/margins applied to them. So, we can remove that in CSS.

Also, because your menu items don't have any spaces, these would ordinarily break out of the box. CSS has been used in the `li` tags to prevent this (word-break: break-word;). Of course, your real menu items may have spaces

```css
body{
   background-color: #018c24
}

li{
  list-style: none;

}

.contenedor{
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 800px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.banner{
  background-image: url(http://www.librosweb.es/website/css/images/logo.gif);
  width: 99%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 15%;
  border-radius: 4px;

}

.about{
  display: table;
 margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;

}

.about li{
  display:inline;
  margin: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.about li:hover{
  background: #f09d28;
  color: #000;

}

.about p{
border-radius: 4px;
display: none;
background-color: #f15647
}

.nav {
  width: 20%;
  height: 81%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: lefT;

}

.nav ul{
  text-align: left;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

.nav ul li{
   word-break: break-word;
}

.principal{
  width: 78%;
  height: 81%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  float:right;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
       <link href="C:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\main.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\prueba.js"></script>

       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>Título de esta página</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="contenedor">
          <div class="banner">
          </div>

          <ul class="about">

                <li>Quiénes somos  </li>
                <p class="caca">CACAasd</p>
                <li>Dónde estamos  </li>
                <p class="caca">CACAasd</p>
                <li>Contacto</li>
                <p>CACAasd</p>

          </ul>

          <div class="nav">
            <ul>
              <li>AAAAAAAAAAA</li>
              <li>BBBBBBBBBBB</li>
              <li>CCCCCCCCCCCCC</li>
              <li>DDDDDDDDDDD</li>
              <li>EEEEEEEEEEEE</li>
              <li>FFFFFFFFFF</li>
              <li>GGGGGGGGGGGG</li>
              <li>HHHHHHHHHHH</li>
              <li>IIIIIIIIIII</li>
              <li>JJJJJJJJJJJJ</li>
              <li>KKKKKKKKKKKKK</li>
              <li>LLLLLLLLLLLLLL</li>
              <li>MMMMMMMMMM</li>
              <li>NNNNNNNNNNNN</li>
              <li>ÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑÑ</li>
              <li>OOOOOOOOOOO</li>
              <li>PPPPPPPPPP</li>
              <li>QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ</li>
              <li>RRRRRRRRRRRRRR</li>
              <li>SSSSSSSSSS</li>
              <p>ACA</p>



            </ul>


          </div>

          <div class="principal">
          </div>




      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add This.

```
.nav {overflow:hidden}
```

and

```
ul{padding:0}
```